# python - Web scraping from Soundcloud

Tags: python, web-scraping

So I'm attempting to scrap the artist/title from my stream on Soundcloud, but after trying my best I keep returning "[]"

My code so far is:

```
import urllib
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://soundcloud.com/stream')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

##Xpath to song headers //*[@id="content"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/ul/li[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/a/span
title = tree.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/ul/li[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/a/span')
print (title)
print(page.url)
```

I'm sure the issue is something silly. I've already attempted it with BS4 as well, but no luck with that either.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't you need to sign in?

Comment: wget https://soundcloud.com/stream returns 401 Unauthorized

Comment: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#authentication

Comment: @ConorPatrick Any idea on a way around this?

Comment: @JarretArmstrong,  I would suggest using the api linked to by idjaw, the site seems to be 99 percent javascript so unless you really know what you are doing it won't be trivial to do what you want.